# How to change the language of the whole interface by command from the user

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter

How can I implement that, for example, the user can select a language from the drop-down list and the whole interface will change to the selected language? I want to implement at least 3 languages: English, Polish, Ukrainian. How can I implement that? The program is written in customtkinter.

```
import customtkinter
import os
from PIL import Image


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("FinPulse")
        self.geometry("750x450")
        self.wm_resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\vladm\Desktop\FinPulseCode\images\logo1.ico')

        # set grid layout 1x2
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # load images with light and dark mode image
        image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "images")
        self.logo_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "logo.png")), size=(40, 40))
        self.kurs = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "kurs_dark.png")),
                                                 dark_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "kurs_light.png")), size=(25, 25))
        self.news = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "news_dark.png")),
                                                 dark_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "news_light.png")), size=(25, 25))
        self.swap = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "swap_dark.png")),
                                                 dark_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "swap_light.png")), size=(25, 25))
        self.settings = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "settings_dark.png")),
                                                 dark_image=Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "settings_light.png")), size=(25, 25))

        # create navigation frame
        self.navigation_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0)
        self.navigation_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.navigation_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.navigation_frame_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.navigation_frame, text="", image=self.logo_image)
        self.navigation_frame_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.kurs_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, corner_radius=0, height=40, border_spacing=10, text="Курси",
                                                   fg_color="transparent", text_color=("gray10", "gray90"), hover_color=("gray70", "gray30"),
                                                   image=self.kurs, anchor="w", command=self.kurs_button_event)
        self.kurs_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.swap_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, corner_radius=0, height=40, border_spacing=10, text="Конвертер",
                                                      fg_color="transparent", text_color=("gray10", "gray90"), hover_color=("gray70", "gray30"),
                                                      image=self.swap, anchor="w", command=self.swap_button_event)
        self.swap_button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.news_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, corner_radius=0, height=40, border_spacing=10, text="Новини",
                                                      fg_color="transparent", text_color=("gray10", "gray90"), hover_color=("gray70", "gray30"),
                                                      image=self.news, anchor="w", command=self.news_button_event)
        self.news_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.settings_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, corner_radius=0, height=40, border_spacing=10, text="Налаштування",
                                                      fg_color="transparent", text_color=("gray10", "gray90"), hover_color=("gray70", "gray30"),
                                                      image=self.settings, anchor="w", command=self.settings_button_event)
        self.settings_button.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="s")

        # create kurs frame
        self.kurs_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")

        # create swap frame
        self.swap_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")

        # create news frame
        self.news_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")

        # create settings frame

        self.values_ukrainian = ["Системи", "Світла", "Темна"]
        self.values_english = ["System", "Light", "Dark"]

        self.settings_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")
        self.settings_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0)
        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.settings_frame, text="Кольорова схема:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.settings_appearance_mode_menu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.settings_frame, values=self.values_ukrainian, command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.settings_appearance_mode_menu.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(0, 20))

        self.scaling_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.settings_frame, text="Масштаб:", anchor="w")
        self.scaling_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.scaling_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.settings_frame, values=["100%", "110%", "120%", "130%", "140%", "150%"], command=self.change_scaling_event)
        self.scaling_optionemenu.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(0, 20))

        # select default frame
        self.select_frame_by_name("kurs")

    def select_frame_by_name(self, name):
        # set button color for selected button
        self.kurs_button.configure(fg_color=("gray75", "gray25") if name == "kurs" else "transparent")
        self.swap_button.configure(fg_color=("gray75", "gray25") if name == "swap" else "transparent")
        self.news_button.configure(fg_color=("gray75", "gray25") if name == "news" else "transparent")
        self.settings_button.configure(fg_color=("gray75", "gray25") if name == "settings" else "transparent")

        # show selected frame
        if name == "kurs":
            self.kurs_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.kurs_frame.grid_forget()
        if name == "swap":
            self.swap_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.swap_frame.grid_forget()
        if name == "news":
            self.news_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.news_frame.grid_forget()
        if name == "settings":
            self.settings_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.settings_frame.grid_forget()

    def kurs_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("kurs")

    def swap_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("swap")

    def news_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("news")

    def settings_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("settings")

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, selected_value):
        index = self.values_ukrainian.index(selected_value)
        english_value = self.values_english[index]
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(english_value)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()[text]
```

I can't find normal documentation or a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a pretty big work but you can do it this way  :

Creating a json for each language you have (`english.json` , `polish.json` etc)

On the creation on your view you need to store all your widget in a dist so you can easily update them afterward.

An `OptionMenu` to allow user to change the current language
This `OptionMenu` will call `change_language` who basicaly load your json in your `self.translation` var and then go througth your dist to update your widget text.

As you can see the text of your widget need to refer to a field of your json

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import json

class MultiLangApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.language_menu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(self, values=["english", "polish"], command=self.change_language)
        self.language_menu.pack()

        self.load_language()

        # Store all text widgets in a dictionary
        self.text_widgets = {
            "greeting": ctk.CTkLabel(self, text=self.translations["greeting"]),
            # Add more widgets here...
        }

        # Pack all widgets
        for widget in self.text_widgets.values():
            widget.pack()

    def load_language(self):
        with open(f"{self.language_menu.get()}.json") as f:
            self.translations = json.load(f)

    def change_language(self, value):
        self.load_language()
        # Update all widgets
        for key, widget in self.text_widgets.items():
            widget.configure(text=self.translations[key])
```

`english.json` :

```
{
    "greeting": "Hello, World!"
}
```

`polish.json` :

```
{
    "greeting": "Hello, World! In polish"
}
```

It's a basic exemple.

Comment: Can you tell me how to connect my code with yours so that everything works correctly? I am new to programming and this assignment is a term project at the university

Comment: I five you an exemple of how toi implement it in a customtkinter app. It's up to you to integrate it in your code. If you need more explaination about my code i can describe it more.If think my answer respond to your question mind to validate it to help other